# Custom IDA Decompilation Coloring

Tags: ida, decompilation, c, ida-plugin

Is there a way to customize the coloring of IDA's decompiled code?

`IDA -> Options -> Colors -> Syntax` doesn't seem to affect the coloring of decompilation.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have three options under `Edit -> Plugins -> Hex-Rays Decompiler -> Options`, see the first three entries under the following image:

[image]

Beyond that, the colors in the pseudocode are governed by `Options -> Color -> Disassembly`. For example, in the following figure, notice that I have `under_debugger` highlighted under the cursor:

[image]

If I use the `Change color` button in the top right to change the color of the imported names in the disassembly listing, it will change the colors in the decompilation too. Here I've changed the color of imported names from magenta to a darker blue:

[image]

Comment: Is there something that correlates all of the coloring options from disasm to decomp? I'd love to understand the rhyme or reason as to why `keywords` coloring also changes `numeric constants` in decompilation code.